# Subversion configuration related question

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, svn, version-control

I've got subversion installed on my Ubuntu server. I usually do my development work under an account separate from root. However, in order to check in code, I need to be root or use the 'su' command 'su svn commit ....'
How do I make it so I can check in code via my regular user account?

Comment: Just to clarify, so the svn repository is on the same machine on which you want to work?

Comment: Yes, the repository is on the same machine that the work is done on.

Comment: The repository probably has root only write access. Chmod 777 *

Answer (score 3):

If the repository is on the same server, then just changing the permissions of the repository folder/files to allow your user to write there should be more than enough.

Better yet, you can create group(s), to which you give write permission(s) on the repo, and add your user to one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your non-root user has read&write access to the directory (and everything below it) where the svn repo is located.

Then, as the non-root user, simply check out a new working copy. You should be able to commit with simply `svn commit`.

If you want to keep using the existing working copy for some reason, one thing you could try is giving the non-root user rw access to everything under all `.ssh` directories  with chown/chmod.

(Assuming here that the repository is on the same machine.)